# Time series Data in Postgres Postgis

Tags: postgresql, time-series, gis, postgis, web-feature-service

I have a time series data that I want to store in a Postgresql-PostGIS db.

the data structure is like this

```
ID t_1  t_2   t_3,  ... t_n
1  33.4 444.4 555.4 ... 644.5
2  36.4 344.4 255.4 ... 744.5
3  45.4 845.4 455.4 ... 844.5
4  66.4 784.4 655.4 ... 344.5
5  44.4 644.4 755.4 ... 544.5
```

I have multiple rows that expres a building ID and multiple columns for the time stamp. I need to store this data in DB in order to elaborate them and provide the values trough a WFS service in a web-gis.

Which is the most efficent way to do so?

Comment: The most efficient way might actually be not to use WFS at all and instead go for an SOS implementation http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sos. You might want to look at the 52north SOS client for that https://52north.org/software/software-projects/sos/. It is build to do what you describe.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at InfluxDB, which is a database system specifically designed for time series data: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfluxDB instead of using postgres, since relational database are not too good at handling time series data